# Veracode Security scan

Tags: java, servlets, veracode, esapi

I ran my application for static analysis, getting Open Redirects flaw.

Here is line of code

```
response.sendRedirect(location.toString());
```

I used below code of ESAPI validator for input validation but still not resolved.

```
if(!ESAPI.validator().isValidRedirectLocation(string, location.toString(), true));
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Starting with the fact that you are verifying a redirect location but call `isValidRequestLocation`. And the main problem is that you do not verify whether or not you want to allow a redirect to that location, e.g. can I use that redirect to send them to https://malicious-site.com via https://yourpage.com/login?redirect=https://malicious.com .

Comment: I just answered this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388049/security-scan-open-redirect-flaw-for-sendredirect/71398094#71398094