# Security scan - open redirect flaw for sendRedirect();

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, veracode, esapi

I ran my application for static analysis, for below line I am getting flaw

response.sendRedirect(location.toString)

I tried with ESAPI input validator as below

if(!ESAPI.validator().isValidRedirectLocation(string, location, true));

But still not resolved

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is really only part of the solution. That is, it is a necessary, but not sufficient step. If `Validator.isValidRedirectLocation()` returns `true`, then you will also want to check '**location**' against an allow-list of acceptable redirect locations.

Also, depending on your SAST tool, it may not recognize this particular correction automatically as remediating it, so you may have to have an AppSec engineer verify it.